# Import dataset in R

Tags: r, import

Sorry possibly very silly question? Couldn't find the answer? How do I load this kind of .dat file in R and stck them in one column? I have been trying

```
NerveData<-as.vector(read.table("D:/Dropbox/nerve.dat", sep=" ")$value)
```

The data set looks like

```
0.21    0.03    0.05    0.11    0.59    0.06
0.18    0.55    0.37    0.09    0.14    0.19
0.02    0.14    0.09    0.05    0.15    0.23
0.15    0.08    0.24    0.16    0.06    0.11
0.15    0.09    0.03    0.21    0.02    0.14
0.24    0.29    0.16    0.07    0.07    0.04
0.02    0.15    0.12    0.26    0.15    0.33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `read.table` with the correct separator. Which in your case is probably `\t`, a tab character.

So try:

```
NerveData = read.table("D:/Dropbox/nerve.dat", sep="\t")
```

Comment: Ah Thanks....I am stupid, sorry new in R, thanks, Really sorry to waste your time for this....Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem at all, don't forget to accept if this answer was helpful to you and vote if you deemed it a quality answer. Don't ever apologize for asking questions btw!

Comment: data is loaded, but actually sorry I want all the columns in column, or simply a vector, but its coming as table, any suggestion??? Thing is I need to find empirical cdf after that, I know that command, but couldn't load the data

Comment: Try `unlist(NerveData)` maybe? Or `as.data.frame(NerveData)` and then selecting the desired column?

Comment: You could also try `columnVector = NerveData[[1]]`. To get the first column as a vector. Maybe unlist isn't the ideal way to go.

Comment: Hold on, let me try in R myself. These comments were just of the top of my head.

Comment: Ok thanks .... just to be more specific, this is the full data http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-nonpar/=data/nerve.dat

Comment: Ok, if you load the table and output it using: `NerveData = ...` followed by `NerveData`. Do you see column titles such as `V1`, `V2` etc? If so you can get the vectors like this: `vector = NerveData$V1`. You can simply change the `V1` part to whatever the column name is!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all the data in as a single vector, use

```
src <- "http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-nonpar/=data/nerve.dat"
NerveData <- scan(src, numeric())
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a easier solution thanks for the initial helps

```
Nervedata<-read.table("nerve.dat",sep ="\t")
Nervedata2<-c(t(Nervedata))
```